# Update only non read only fields of a SharePoint list using client object model

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, sharepoint-server

How to upadate only non read only fields of a SharePoint list using client object model? The code sample is working fine for a particular field like title

```
        string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");
        ListItem oListItem = oList.Items.GetById(3);
        oListItem["Title"] = "My Updated Title.";
        oListItem.Update();
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But I have an array containing values of all fields of the list and want to update all non read only fields of the list(not a particular field like title) using client object model.
Any code example or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the fields collection from CSOM

```
SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List Title Here"); 
SP.FieldCollection fieldColl = oList.Fields;
clientContext.Load(fieldColl);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

After that you can check the "ReadOnlyField" Property of the field.

OR

```
Field field = list.Fields.GetByTitle("Title");
clientContext.Load(field);
```

Then check  field.ReadOnlyField  property

Also Check [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/13514e1c-3fbc-4106-8cfc-0eb11abb39e2/programmatically-determining-if-a-field-is-readonly-using-the-sharepoint-2010-managed-client-object?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)